# Is there a completely reliable way to check (synchronous / asynchronous) if Google Maps is fully loaded?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API v 3.11 (latest as of now)

- The event 'idle' sometimes gets fired even if there are some tiles which are not loaded due to slow internet connection.
- The event 'tilesloaded' does not get fired all the time. It only gets fired when some tiles were really loaded. If the tiles are coming from cache, this event does not get fired at all. So your listener may keep waiting endlessly.

How does somebody makes sure that the tiles in a map are completely loaded?

Is there a function which can tell me whether the tiles are completely loaded? In that case I could listen to 'idle' event and then check for this areTilesLoaded() function and then listen to another 'tilesloaded' event?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: My use-case is that I am zooming on the map and then I need to take an action when the tiles are completely loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I've used

```
google.maps.event.addListener( map, 'idle', function() {
    // do cool stuff
});
```

to fire off something when the map was idle and (so I thought) fully loaded. Can you toss your use-case up into a fiddle, or provide something for us to see?

Comment: Hi Mac, The event 'idle' sometimes gets fired even if there are some tiles which are not loaded due to slow internet connection. Specially if the browser in opening the map for first time. (Try clearing the cache to simulate this, or open the map in incognito mode).

Comment: Hi Mac, I did try bounds_changed. But sometimes when there are no bounds changing, the listener waits endlessly.